# Nextjs Async Thunks

Tags: typescript, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to create an async thunk to grab data from my db and store it in my state using NextJs and reduxjs/toolkit. Firstly, I don't know if this is a great idea or not, I'm trying to limit my requests as much as possible and store the data globally so I can access it anywhere in my app.

I'm planning to dispatch the action to fetch data in my homepage so that the data is available asap because there are some action buttons to access data in the homepage.

This is my slice:

```
"use client";

import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { IDisplateInfo } from "@/app/types/types";

import axios from "axios";

import type { PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const fetchDisplates = createAsyncThunk("getDisplates", async () => {
  const response = await axios.get("api/displates");
  if (response.status === 200) {
    const displates = response.data;
    return displates;
  }
});

export interface DisplateState {
  displates: IDisplateInfo[];
  currentDisplate: IDisplateInfo;
  favoriteDisplates: IDisplateInfo[];
  displateCategories: IDisplateInfo[];
}

const initialState: DisplateState = {
  displates: [],
  currentDisplate: {
    img: null,
    title: null,
    category: null,
    id: null,
  },
  favoriteDisplates: [],
  displateCategories: [],
};

export const displateSlice = createSlice({
  name: "displate",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setDisplates: (state, action: PayloadAction<IDisplateInfo[]>) => {
      state.displates = action.payload;
    },
    setCurrentDisplate: (state, action: PayloadAction<IDisplateInfo>) => {
      state.currentDisplate = action.payload;
    },
    setFavoriteDisplates: (state, action: PayloadAction<IDisplateInfo[]>) => {
      state.favoriteDisplates = action.payload;
    },
    setDisplateCategories: (state, action: PayloadAction<IDisplateInfo[]>) => {
      state.displateCategories = action.payload;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchDisplates.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.displates = action.payload;
    });
  },
});

export const {
  setCurrentDisplate,
  setDisplates,
  setFavoriteDisplates,
  setDisplateCategories,
} = displateSlice.actions;

export default displateSlice.reducer;
```

And my get function:

```
export const GET = cache(async (request: Request) => {
  const currentUser = getCurrentUser();

  console.log(request);

  const displates = await prisma.displateInfo.findMany();

  return NextResponse.json(displates);
});
```

Here's my store:

```
"use client";

import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import userReducer from "../redux/features/user/userSlice";
import displateReducer from "./features/displate/displateSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
    displate: displateReducer,
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

But when I call the action in my component:

```
dispatch(fetchDisplates());
```

I get the following error:

```
Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, void, AsyncThunkConfig>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.ts(2345)
```

Maybe my approach is wrong, I'm not sure its the first time I'm using reduxjs with Nextjs so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does the Redux store creation code look like? Can you [edit] to provide a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: Sure, I edited it and provided the store code

Comment: Thunks will definitely work, but you could also use [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) for data fetching and caching.

Comment: Agreed, thunks should work since you didn't go out of the way to exclude in when configuring the store. Is there a code stacktrace accompanying that error that might indicate where in the code the issue is? Specifically only when `fetchDisplates` is dispatched? Can you [edit] to show where & how `fetchDisplates` is dispatched? I don't see any overt issues otherwise.

Comment: Ah I found the issue, endpoint was incorrect. Sorry for the trouble